# Safari 11 crash on 10.13 with CSS using font-feature-settings for open type features

Tags: css, html, safari, opentype

I defined a couple of styles using font-feature-setting

```
.text-openType-Case {
    font-family:'Adobe Caslon Pro','ACaslonPro-Regular';
    font-feature-settings:"case";
}
.text-openType-Numr {
    font-family:'Adobe Caslon Pro','ACaslonPro-Regular';
    font-feature-settings:"numr";
}
```

If I use them on a couple of spans, Safari crashes

```
<p>
    <span class="text-openType-Case">A</span>
    <span class="text-openType-Numr">1</span>
</p>
```

Some observations:

1. It crashes in 11.0.2, 11.0.3 (checked on High Sierra).
2. Its not font specific. Crashed with other fonts too which support the features used in styles
3. It doesn't crash if only single style was used.
4. Its not specific to combination of 'numr' or 'case' features. e.g. it crashes for 'case' & 'ornm' too.
5. The crash happens if the font is installed on system, It doesn't crash if the font is referred from some url in font-face rule and the font is not available on system.
6. Found the crash log: It says
   **Crashing on exception: -[__NSCFNumber compare:]: nil argument**

I suspect it to be a Safari bug so I reported a bug on bugreporter.apple.com a few weeks ago.

**Can anyone please suggest a work-around other than not using font-feature-setting?** Here is a very minimal snippet:

```css
    .text-openType-Case {
        font-family:'Adobe Caslon Pro','ACaslonPro-Regular';
        font-feature-settings:"case";
    }
    .text-openType-Numr {
        font-family:'Adobe Caslon Pro','ACaslonPro-Regular';
        font-feature-settings:"numr";
    }
```

```html
<p>
    <span class="text-openType-Case">A</span>
    <span class="text-openType-Numr">1</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Please file this over on https://bugs.webkit.org/ so that the people who actually know everything about the safari codebase (which is just the webkit codebase, only the application UI you interact with is "safari") can figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for link. I submitted a bug here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183323

Comment: very nice. If an answer is forthcoming there, it'll be worth copying that over as answer here.

Comment: Sure, I'll definitely do that.

Comment: I didn't get any response so far.

Comment: Indeed. Although of course we're now on Safari 16.2, both on MacOS 12 and 13, so I guess check if it's still the case? And if it is, post an update to report that and hopefully someone sees it (but yeah, definitely not hold your breath I guess =S)